# Firestore/Javascript: Is it possible to update an old document and set a new document at the same time (one javascript execution)?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

What I am trying to accomplish is on a click of a button the `<script>` will execute 2 document actions. the first action will update an old `document` in this case a `document` named Nov 30, 2019, and change one of its fields named `isActive` to `false`. The second Action will set a new `document` named whatever current date the user will execute the said action.

At the moment none of the said actions is working. But the second action is working prior to adding this code **(this is supposed to be the first action code which updates the old document's field)**:

```
let userRef1 = firebase.firestore().collection("users").doc(userId).collection("goal").orderBy("dateAdded", "desc").limit(1);
                                            return userRef1.get()
                                            .then(function(querySnapshot) {
                                                querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
                                                    console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
                                                    this.getDateBeforeUpdate = doc.id; //this get the document ID or the date in this case (Nov 30, 2019)
                                            });
                                        })

                                    await firebase.firestore().collection("users").doc(userId).collection("goal").doc(getDateBeforeUpdate).update({
                                        'isActive': false,
                                        });
```

Here is the full code that does both actions:

```
                                let userRef1 = firebase.firestore().collection("users").doc(userId).collection("goal").orderBy("dateAdded", "desc").limit(1);
                                        return userRef1.get()
                                        .then(function(querySnapshot) {
                                            querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
                                                console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
                                                this.getDateBeforeUpdate = doc.id; //this get the document ID or the date in this case (Nov 30, 2019)
                                        });
                                    })

                                await firebase.firestore().collection("users").doc(userId).collection("goal").doc(getDateBeforeUpdate).update({
                                    'isActive': false,
                                    });

                                if( getDateAndConsent.getGoalDate.getTime() >= date1.addDays().getTime() ){
                                     if(getDateAndConsent.getYN == "Yes"){
                                        await firebase.firestore().collection("users").doc(userId).collection("goal").doc(americanDate).set({
                                            'startRange': startRange, 'endRange': endRange, 'dateAdded': data.dateAdded, 
                                            'isActive': data.isActive, 'doesmaintainBG': data.doesMaintainBG, 'goalDate': firebase.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(data.goalDate),
                                            'goalWeight': data.inputWeight, 'goalForWeight': data.goalForWeight,
                                        })
                                        .then(function(){
                                            window.alert("Weight goal updated!");
                                            window.location.href = "diabetesManagement.php"; 
                                        })
                                        .catch(function(error){
                                            console.log("Error updating weight goal: ", error);
                                            window.alert("Error updating weight goal: " + error);
                                        })
                                    }
                                    else if(getDateAndConsent.getYN == "No"){
                                        await firebase.firestore().collection("users").doc(userId).collection("goal").doc(americanDate).set({
                                            'dateAdded': data.dateAdded, 'isActive': data.isActive, 
                                            'doesmaintainBG': data.doesMaintainBG, 'goalDate': firebase.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(data.goalDate),
                                            'goalWeight': data.inputWeight, 'goalForWeight': data.goalForWeight,
                                        })
                                        .then(function(){
                                            window.alert("Weight goal updated!");
                                            window.location.href = "diabetesManagement.php"; 
                                        })
                                        .catch(function(error){
                                            console.log("Error updating weight goal: ", error);
                                            window.alert("Error updating weight goal: " + error);
                                        });
                                    }
                                    else{
                                        window.alert("error");
                                    }
                                }
                                else{
                                    window.alert("error date: you can only input dates three weeks from now");
                                    window.location.href = "diabetesManagement.php"; 
                                }
```

**Image of the database:**
[image]
When the whole action is executed the encircled database the encircled field will be updated. Then afterward a new document will be created named/id the current date.

Comment: To write two documents at the same time, you should look into transactions and batched writes.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions

Comment: You also dont need `await` along side the `.then()`. Instead, surround the expression with a try catch block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though I gave Doug Stevenson's answer a try. I'm still having a hard time implementing it. I do found a workaround though by using `setTimeout()` upon clicking the button the first query will run. While the second one will be paused for 3 seconds before executing.

the code goes like this:

```
                                if( getDateAndConsent.getGoalDate.getTime() >= date1.addDays().getTime() ){
                                     if(getDateAndConsent.getYN == "Yes"){
                                        firebase.firestore().collection("users").doc(userId).collection("goal").where("isActive", "==", true)
                                        .get()
                                        .then(function(querySnapshot) {
                                            querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
                                                console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
                                                this.getDateBeforeUpdate = doc.id; //this get the document ID or the date in this case (Nov 30, 2019)
                                                firebase.firestore().collection("users").doc(userId).collection("goal").doc(getDateBeforeUpdate).update({
                                                    'isActive': false,
                                                })
                                            })
                                        })
                                        setTimeout(function(){firebase.firestore().collection("users").doc(userId).collection("goal").doc(americanDate).set({
                                            'startRange': startRange, 'endRange': endRange, 'dateAdded': data.dateAdded, 
                                            'isActive': true, 'doesmaintainBG': data.doesMaintainBG, 'goalDate': firebase.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(data.goalDate),
                                            'goalWeight': data.inputWeight, 'goalForWeight': data.goalForWeight,
                                        })
                                        .then(function(){
                                            window.alert("Weight goal updated!");
                                            window.location.href = "diabetesManagement.php"; 
                                        })
                                        .catch(function(error){
                                            console.log("Error updating weight goal: ", error);
                                            window.alert("Error updating weight goal: " + error);
                                        })}, 3000);
                                    }
```

Though it seems unorthodox, I do still consider it a workaround. Hope this helps if you are having a hard time implementing `transactions` or `batch`!